Wolfram Quantum Framework: simple NOT gate: strange matrix of circuit
Please have a look at the attached notebook.
It contains a simple NOT circuit.
I would expect the matrix of the circuit to be a 2 by 2 matrix.
Just like the 2 by 2 matrix of the NOT gate itself.
But in the Wolfram Quantum Framework it is a 4 by 2 matrix.
How can this be explained?
PacletInstall["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"]
Needs["Wolfram`QuantumFramework`"]
ops = {QuantumOperator["NOT", {1}], QuantumMeasurementOperator["ComputationalBasis", {1}]};
circuit = QuantumCircuitOperator[ops]
circuit["Diagram"]
circuit["Matrix"] // MatrixForm
QuantumOperator["NOT", {1}]["Matrix"] // MatrixForm

The first matrix (of the circuit) is 4 by 2.
The second matrix (of the NOT gate) is the expected 2 by 2.
How can this be explained?
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3165145

Please make this question self-sufficient by providing the complete code instead of just giving the link to another site :) (Keep the link only at the end as the reference.)
